# tabBarController?.selectedIndex not switching VC's

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController embedded inside a container view. The first tab has a collection view and on didselectitematindex i call

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

and it switches to the other view controller successfully. HOWEVER when I call

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

it doesn't switch to the index 0. In fact it doesn't do anything. I've tried putting a button on selectedIndex 2 and calling that command from there but it doesn't work. I've tried adding self. to the call but doesn't work. I've tried calling a function that makes the call but that doesn't work either. I've also made sure that my tabBarController has the storyboard ID "tabBarController". My tabBarController doesn't have a class attached to it but I don't think it needs one because the first View controller switch worked without it.

Whats wrong here?

I guess it does matter why its not working if someone can give me another way to switch view controllers programatically.

Let me know if you need more information.

project is here on github
https://github.com/applegaming/hots-buddy

Comment: from where u using tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 , if any tabbar has default viewcontroller then it works but if u invoke this from inside of viewcontroler -> viewcontroller then it wont work

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari I'm do not understand "invoke this from inside of viewcontroler -> view controller".  I just started programming a month ago. The first call (the one the works) is made from the did select item at index path which is inside the view controller at index 0. I have added a button  to the view controller at index 1 and call it from an IBAction but that doesn't work either.

Comment: upload project on git , wil make changes accordingly

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari   you can find it at https://github.com/applegaming/hots-buddy

Answer (score 6):

Because you haven't to call TabBarController using self, because you still are in the class of TabBarController.

So you have to use :

```
self.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: Thats the real solution.